# How to obtain the daily difference in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

example =

```
day | hours 
monday  5
monday   6
tuesday  5
tuesday  6
tuesday  7
wednesday 5
wednesday 6
wednesday 7
```

Expected Result:

```
day | hours
monday 1
tuesday 2
wednesday 2
```

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't think OP wants a plain `groupby` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to subtract only `first` and `last` row from each group.

Use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), pick [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) rows per group. Then, use [`df.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
In [3831]: x = (
      ...:     df.groupby("day")
      ...:     .agg({"hours": ["first", "last"]})
      ...:     .diff(axis=1)[("hours", "last")]
      ...:     .reset_index()
      ...:     .droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
      ...: )

In [3829]: x
Out[3829]: 
         day  hours
0     monday    1.0
1    tuesday    2.0
2  wednesday    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I read it too fast, let's try:

```
df.groupby('day', as_index=False)['hours'].apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

Or

```
df.groupby('day', as_index=False)['hours'].apply(np.ptp)
```

Output:

```
         day  hours
0     monday      1
1    tuesday      2
2  wednesday      2
```